# How to save 'contenteditable' on database

Tags: php, contenteditable

```
<tr contenteditable>
<td><center><?php echo $nama    = $isi['nama']; ?></center> </td>
<td><center><?php echo $jk  =  $isi['jk']; ?></center> </td>
```

I have this code, 
And I dunno how to save it on my database.
if you guys don't mind, you can check the picture here : http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img673/4384/Ww9PKg.jpg

Comment: It's not clear what you want to save in your database. Do you want to save the content of that table? What do you mean with saving contenteditable in database?

Comment: yeah, I wanna save the content of the table to my database, 
at first I'm showing my database on php, then I want to edit its content, and i have no idea how to save it ...

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is instead of making the table content editable, and allow users to change it, put the data that will be updated on input fields, and post to your PHP script to save:

```
<form action="/post.php" method="post">
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="nama-0" value="<?php echo $nama = $isi['nama']; ?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="jk-0" value="<?php echo $jk  =  $isi['jk']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

But if you still need to use the table without the input elements (I've no idea why that'd be required) then use javascript to extract the values from table, and then submit to your PHP script.